# Why CredentialCache class requires a full qualified name?

Tags: c#

Just wondering Why CredentialCache class requires a full qualified name?

for example

```
using System.Net;

namespace test
{
class tc
{

public void tm()
{
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; //error
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; //no error
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't. But you omitted a `;` after `using System.Net`.

### Update

Okay, so the error message leads to the assumption that you have a member in your class that has the name `CredentialCache`. Since the C# specification states that a name is resolved from inside to outside, it picks this member before it gets to System.Net.CredentialCache (for a precise explanation see *ECMA 334 4th Ed. C# Language Specification — C#, 10.8 Namespace and type names* (from top of my head)).

You can reproduce this behaviour with a class like this:

```
using System.Net;

namespace NameResolution{
public class TestUnqualifiedNameResolution {
    public DoSomething(){
        Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.Authenti‌‌​​cationCredentials> CredentialCache = new Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.Authenti‌‌​​cationCredentials>();
        //Fully qualified name is resolved to the type you are looking for, because the Dictionary does not match the name
        var credentialCache0 = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        //Unqualified name is resolved to the nearest matching (here the Dictionary)
        var credentialCache1 = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    }
}
}
```

By renaming the wrongly resolved member, CredentialCache will be resolved to System.Net.CredentialCache as you expect.

### Just for fun

The following code is also valid (but you should never write something like this):

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication {
    class Program {
        static void Main()
        {
                        // That's a System.Int32!
            int a = System.Net.CredentialCache;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} == System.Int32", a.GetType().FullName);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static class System
        { 
            public static Net Net { get { return new Net(); } }
        }
        public class Net
        {
            public int CredentialCache { get { return 0; } }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's true, but since it's the only error in the code the op provided, I assumed that he misinterpreted the error message.

Comment: The error is NOT because of ; after using System.Net. I just fixed that in my question. Here is the error details: Error 2 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.AuthenticationCredentials>' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultNetworkCredentials' and no extension method 'DefaultNetworkCredentials' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.AuthenticationCredentials>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't result in an error unless you have another `CredentialCache` class in scope and the compiler doesn't know how to correctly resolve the symbol.

You should be able to determine that from the actual error text.

Comment: Here is the error details: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.Authenti‌​cationCredentials>' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultNetworkCredentials' and no extension method 'DefaultNetworkCredentials' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.Authentic‌​ationCredentials>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

CredentialCache itself doesn't require a full qualified name. The problem must be somewhere else. You may have defined another CredentialCache class in your test namespace. 
In order to help more, I need to know what error you are getting and what is that credentials variable in credentials.Windows.ClientCredential. Where have you defined it and what is its type?

Comment: Here is the error details:   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.AuthenticationCredentials>' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultNetworkCredentials' and no extension method 'DefaultNetworkCredentials' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.AuthenticationCredentials>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)